# create nested array from string with delimiter

Tags: php

I has a string like as  `brachA-branchB-branchC`. I am trying to make it as nested array as follows

```
 [
    'name'=>'brachA',
    'sub'=> [
             'name'=>'brachB',
             'sub'=>[
                 'name'=>'brachC'
               ]
            ]
 ]
```

I tried as follows (https://3v4l.org/A781D)

```
<?php
$nested_array = array();
$temp = &$nested_array;
$item = 'brachA-branchB-branchC';

foreach (explode('-', $item) as $key => $value) {
      $temp = &$temp[$value];
}

print_r($nested_array);
```

Output I am getting as follows

```
Array
(
    [brachA] => Array
        (
            [branchB] => Array
                (
                    [branchC] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Any idea, how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can probably be done using a `foreach` loop over the reversed array returned by `explode()` but it is much easier to use a recursive function.

```
function makeArray(array $pieces)
{
    $first = array_shift($pieces);

    $array = array('name' => $first);
    if (count($pieces)) {
        $array['sub'] = makeArray($pieces);
    }

    return $array;
}

$item = 'brachA-branchB-branchC';
print_r(makeArray(explode('-', $item)));
```

The `makeArray()` function receives an array with the string pieces. It puts the first item under the `'name'` key of a new array and invokes itself with the rest of the array to generate the array to put under the `'sub'` key. It doesn't put anything for the `'sub'` key if there is no rest (on the last call, `$pieces` is `array('brachC')`.